# Application menus are not showing

Tags: menu

I installed elementary OS today and found that in some applications the menus are not shown when clicked. It is not like I see the menu but not the text of the items, but rather that if I click on an item in the menubar, it is marked but the corresponding menu does not open.

So far I have that problem in lyx, vlc, yakuake and dolphin. Other applications like google-chrome or software-center work fine.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can u post a screenshot, use [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) for menus

Comment: I have no idea why but after putting the laptop in sleeping mode and waking it up again, the menus now work just fine. Thank you for your help.